# debugger suddenly stopped working in webstorm project

Tags: webstorm

My webstorm ide won't stop on breakpoints in my existing Node.js project anymore.

It seems to work fine when I create a new webstorm node.js express project and set a debug point.

For example, for a very simple test, I create a file in my existing project called test.js:

```
var name = 'bob';
console.log(name);
```

create a run/debug configuration

```
Name:test
Path to Node:/usr/local/bin/node
workding directory: Path to my directory
Path to Node App JS file: test.js
```

I set a break point to line 1 which never gets hit, even though the program runs fine.  How can I get the debugger to hit breakpoints again on this project.

Output

```
/usr/local/bin/node --debug-brk=64597 test.js
debugger listening on port 64597
bob

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The same project copied into another directory works fine in the debugger.  However if I keep it in the same directory, even if I delete the .idea folder and recreate the debug configuration from scratch it won't attach to the debugger.

I was playing around with JSTestDriver settings earlier.. could that have affected things and continued to affect things even though the .idea folder was deleted?

Comment: Any symlinks in the current project directory?

Comment: nope, and it was working just a week ago..

Answer (score 3):

The same thing happened to me as well.  I finally rebooted my machine and Webstorm started hitting breakpoints again.  It's not a great answer, but at least it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Rename (delete) the **.idea** folder from the root of your project and try again.

**[edit]**
as @Silvio Biasiol suggested, you better do a backup of your `.idea` folder before moving/renaming/removing it. The `.idea` folder actually contains temporary but sometimes important information (i.e. Webstorm has its inner version controlling history, which might be vital for some people) that you might want to recover later.

Comment: Helped me as well but I would suggest you to make a copy of your `.idea` folder before deleting it in case you loose smth important

Answer (score 0):

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB may be is more suitable place for report WebStorm bugs ;) http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2313 may be related.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, my express app stop working with code 0.

I've placed breakpoint in the first line of my code and just step over. At some point I found that one of my controllers returned undefined and caused process to exit.

After fix I recieved standard express is listening on port xxxx